# Query_post , pegar a taxonomy pelo campo personalizado do post

Tags: php, wordpress

Bom dia a todos. 
Um uma page tenho um campo personalizado com o nome de um post_type  .
No query_post esto querendo pegar o valor que esta não campo personalizado com o nome (escolha)

a $escolha é o valor que pego no campo personalizado.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nao sei se da para compreender a minha pergunta, mas agradeço qual quer ajuda

Comment: não use query_posts -> https://codex.wordpress.org/pt-br:Refer%C3%AAncia_de_Fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o/query_posts

Answer (score 2):

Se entendi sua pergunta, pois está bem estranha, parece que quer resgatar o valor do meta field, para isso, bastaria o seguinte código.

```
<!-- Quando está dentro do loop de posts e possui o post alimentado corretamente -->
<?php $escolha = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'escolha', true ); ?>


<!-- Quando está fora do Loop ou precisa passar o ID manualmente -->
<?php $escolha = get_post_meta( "ID_DO_POST", 'escolha', true ); ?>
```

Caso queira resgatar todos os meta fields, você pode ocultar o campo, assim o WordPress retornará todos.

```
<!-- Caso não esteja dentro do Loop, passe o ID do post no lugar de get_the_ID() -->
<?php $metas = get_post_meta( get_the_ID() ); ?>
```

Agora, se quer resgatar todos os posts com um determinado meta field e determinado valor:

```
$args = array(
   'meta_query' => array(
       array(
           'key' => 'escolha',
           'value' => 'valor_do_seu_meta_campo',
           'compare' => '=',
       )
   )
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Com o nome da categoria em mãos, você pode resgatar os posts da seguinte forma:

```
$category = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'escolha', true);

$query = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'category_name'  => $category,
        'orderby'        => 'title',
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
    )
);
```

Comment: Ola Bruno 
Esta fora do loop, fiz o teste para pegar o valor do campo assim:
$category = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'escolha', true)
echo $category (o valor aparece sem problema)

Depois vai o query_post
query_posts('$category=categoria-todas-familia & showposts= -1 &showposts= 3 & orderby=title');

PS: Peço desculpa ainda estou a tentar de como se coloca o código na pergunta

Comment: Adicionei no final como pegar os posts com o slug da categoria.

Comment: Já tinha experimentado desta forma, mas a query_post não pega o valor

Comment: O slug da sua categoria está exatamente igual? Se possuir espaço não vai encontrar.

Comment: Em vez de ter no início ( ‘ ) deveria ter ( “ ) query_posts("$category=categoria-todas-familia & showposts= -1 &showposts= 3 & orderby=title") Obrigada pela ajuda

Answer (score 0):

Em vez de ter no início ( ‘ ) deveria ter ( “ )

```
query_posts("$category=categoria-todas-familia & showposts= -1 &showposts= 3 & orderby=title")
```